# How can I tell if my bike has a freewheel or a cassette?

Tags: gears, cassette, freewheel

I bought a Frankenbike off Craigslist.

[image: frankenbike]

It's a Specialized Rockhopper of unknown year, converted to a commuter, with shocks up front and V-brakes.

I love this weird little bike and want to put a [Copenhagen wheel](https://www.superpedestrian.com) on it when they come out, to make it into the ultimate commuter frankenbike.

To install the wheel I'll need to know whether I'm dealing with a freewheel or a cassette. How can I find out without taking the bike apart or knowing the year it was built?

Comment: And why do you need to know if it is freewheel or cassette to install the wheel?  The wheel installs the same and works the same.

Comment: Kibbee's advice of posting a close up for confirmation is a good one, but guessing the age of the bike based on the components and Specialized graphics I'm 90% sure you have a cassette.

Comment: Yeah, A Specialized bike of that age would most likely have a cassette, but as the OP mentioned, it's a "frankenbike" which means many parts have been changed out. So it's probably worth verifying.

Comment: @Blam I read that if installing on a freewheel machine I would need to adjust the derailleurs (which for me would mean getting help instead of doing it myself).

Comment: What age would you guys say the frame is, based on the graphics etc?

Comment: Mid to late '90s

Comment: Also, you'll likely need a derailleur adjustment regardless of whether the Copenhagen Wheel has a cassette or freewheel. It's not hard though, and definitely worth learning. (Sorry, for putting this here, I can't comment above.)

Answer (score 10):

If you take the back wheel off you should be able to examine the freewheel/cassette to determine which it is. Here is a picture of some common types. If yours doesn't look like one in the picture, post a close up and I'm sure someone here can identify it.

[image]